# creating methods within an interation in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

The code below obviously does not work, but this is what I had in mind. Is there a way to create methods like the two below using `item`, without repeating the `doc.css(".main_entry").each do |item|` over and over?

```
class Scraper      
.
.
.
  doc.css(".main_entry").each do |item|
    def artist 
      @artist ||= item.at_css(".list_artist").text
    end

    def title
      @title ||= item.at_css(".list_album").text
    end
  end
.
.
.
end

puts scraper.artist
puts scraper.title
```

Comment: in your scenario ..are you trying to call artist and title method multiple times ? ..

Comment: There will be multiple `.main_entry` items in `doc`, each with its own artist and title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it. However, method scopes don't nest, the only construct in Ruby that creates a nested scope is a block. Thankfully, there is a method for defining methods that takes a block as an argument:

```
class Scraper      
.
.
.
  doc.css(".main_entry").each do |item|
    define_method(:artist) do 
      @artist ||= item.at_css(".list_artist").text
    end

    define_method(:title) do
      @title ||= item.at_css(".list_album").text
    end
  end
.
.
.
end

puts scraper.artist
puts scraper.title
```

However, note that this has the exact same problem that your original code would have had if it had worked: you are simply overwriting the same method over and over and over again.

Comment: Thank you! And what causes it to overwrite? I can't tell if this is related but the iterator portion of the code does not work because `doc` is undefined. Under `private`, it's `def doc    @doc ||= Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))    end`

Comment: @sivanes Why wouldn't you expect them to be overwritten, the code is looping and redefining functions with the same name every time, before the functions are used. It seems you don't need to definie functions at all, you just need to push the artist/title to an array each time or print them out.